# Element ref was specified as a string (view) but no owner was set when fork and edit the repo

Tags: reactjs, git, npm-scripts, git-fork, react-big-calendar

I was working on a react project and using **react-big-calendar**. We need a feature that isn't supported yet by **react-big-calendar**, so I forked the project, updated the code (checked it locally with `yarn run examples`) and commit to the GitHub.

[My updated repo link](https://github.com/EngrKhizarIqbal/react-big-calendar)

I've tried to install the repo with these commands:

```
yarn install https://github.com/EngrKhizarIqbal/react-big-calendar/tarball/b8e3881ab7b3b4722406f9ede35f2c1f96eadc5b
yarn install https://github.com/EngrKhizarIqbal/react-big-calendar.git
yarn install https://github.com/EngrKhizarIqbal/react-big-calendar/tarball/master
yarn install E:/Web/React/ReactCalander/react-big-calendar
```

I also navigated to the **node_modules/react-big-calendar** and run the following scripts

```
yarn install
yarn run build
```

So, when I am trying to use this updated package in a project, I'm getting the following error.

> Element ref was specified as a string (view) but no owner was set.
>
> This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You may be adding a ref to a function component
> 2. You may be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's render method
> 3. You have multiple copies of React loaded

Here is the package.json of the project where I'm using updated-repo

```json
"dependencies": {
    "react-dom": "16.5.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "react-big-calendar": "E:/Web/React/ReactCalander/r/react-big-calendar",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
},
"scripts": {
    "prestart": "cls",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "prebuild": "cls",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

It is the first time I'm modifying an open souce project.

Thanks in advance for your help.